# Иконка скрипта отображается как шестеренка

Tags: unity3d

Заметил, что на одном из прикрепленных скриптов, иконка не такая как на других. Также, иконка другая и в обозревателе проекта.

Нормальная иконка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Новая странная иконка (такие иконки у файлов настроек unity):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Почему сменилась иконка? Влияет ли это каким-то образом на проект?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Некоторые иконки закреплены по имени за конкретными скриптами, чтобы при добавлении компонентов на объект они явственно выделялись. Вы можете самостоятельно задавать свои иконки для конкретных скриптов, что может стать удобным инструментом по быстрому поиску конкретных компонентов на сцене и в инспекторе. Если вам не нравится эта иконка - можете её сменить. И нет, никак на работу проекта это не влияет, просто фича для удобства.
[Подробнее в документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssigningIcons.html)

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, из-за названия, "Game Manager" по дефолту у Unity имеет другое изображение, попробуйте изменить название скрипта если иконка вас смущает/путает.